# Shell - When i use ${file[@]} and for, equal is not working

Tags: windows, shell

I write a code style checker on Ubuntu, this nice work. but now, i use windows 7 system.

In windows git bash, I want file list and check string equal, this bad working, I try this code:

- list file(/run_file/test)

```
E:/Code/code.uio

models/test.php,php,js
public/test.php,html,php
```

- checker file(/run)

```sh
rootPath=$(cd `dirname $0`; pwd)
aimPath=`head -1 ${rootPath}/run_file/$1`

cd ${aimPath}

while read -r line
do
    if [[ "$line" != "$aimPath" ]]
    then
        # get file and checker
        IFS=',' file=(${line})

        for index in "${file[@]}"
        do
            # skipping this file name
            if [[ ${index} = "${file[0]}" ]]; then
                continue
            fi

            if [[ "${index}" = "php" ]]; then
                echo "Index Matched"
            else
                echo "Index is NOT Matched ${index}.ABC"
            fi;

            if [[ "${index}" = php* ]]; then
                echo "Index Matched and has other sign"
            else
                echo "Index is NOT Matched..."
            fi;
        done
    fi
done < ${rootPath}/run_file/$1
```

The code tell me `.ABCIndex is NOT Matched php` and `Index Matched and has other sign`

Why `has other sign`? I'm code has error? I completely puzzled.

*PS:*

You can look [Checker repository - GitHub](https://github.com/Sun-FreePort/MiaoSiLaCheck)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I miss windows is `CRLF`, so this `other sign` is line break (`\r`).